# Change part of the middle of the name

Tags: batch-file

I need help (I'm already banging my head on the wall), I have several files that I want to change part of the middle of the name.
example:

```
scan1234.pdf_page02.pdf -> to -> scan1234_page01.pdf
```

I Tried

```
ren *.pdf_page??.pdf *_page??.pdf
```

but it did not work...

that is, I need to delete the text ".pdf" from the middle of the name. can help me?

Comment: Can we assume you didn't mean to change the page number from `02` to `01`?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a batch file containing:

   ```
   for %%f in (scan????.pdf_page??.pdf) do call :renamefile "%%~f"
   exit /b
   :renamefile
   set "FILENAME=%~1"
   ren "%~1" "%FILENAME:.pdf_=_%"
   exit /b
   ```
2. Run it.

Explanation:

- The `for` statement iterates over all files matching `scan????.pdf_page??.pdf` and calls the subroutine `:renamefile` with `%1` set to the filename. If the pattern is too strict you may try `scan*.pdf_page*.pdf` -- I cannot tell whether there are exact four digits after `scan` and two after `page`.
- The `ren` command uses substring replacement in the variable substitution to replace `.pdf_` with `_`.

Comment: @Sweeper If the `.pdf` in the middle might ever _not_ be followed by an underscore, as in your example, simply removing the underscores in AlexP's answer would also remove the trailing `.pdf` extension. If you needed to do this, using `"FILENAME=%~n1"` would just get the name part (e.g. `scan1234.pdf_page01`) and you could then safely do `ren "%~1" "%FILENAME:.pdf=%.pdf"` without the underscores (but note the extra `.pdf` to restore the extension).

Comment: @TripeHound I prefer then use `ren "%~1" "%FILENAME:.pdf=%%~x1"`